# Make tables render as one next & materialui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, apollo, strapi

Currently I am using NextJs and MaterialUI to render a table with results from an API I have made in Strapi.

##### Issue

Currently the issue is that I am using a table component with props that I then import into a page and map the props to an api response from a GraphQl request (I use Apollo), I want the data to create multiple rows instead of multiple tables.

We can see from the image that when using the props it renders two tables but with the correct results. However If I map the data inside the table component it creates multiple rows this is the way I want it to work but with using props so I am not just creating up ten or more tables. I have left code below.

How do I use the table with props but without it creating multiple tables?

[image: tables issue]

##### Testing page

```
import { Heading, VStack } from "@chakra-ui/react";
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";
import { Typography } from "@mui/material";
import React from "react";
import { TableTwo } from "../src/components/UI/tableTwo";
import { TestingTable } from "../src/components/UI/tableTest";

const British = gql`
  query {
    britishes {
      data {
        attributes {
          Role_Name
          British_Roles {
            role_name
            Primary
            Primary_Sights
            Primary_Firing_Modes
            Primary_Magazine_Amount
            Primary_Magazine_Round_Amount
            Secondary
            Secondary_Firing_Modes
            Secondary_Sights
            Secondary_Magazine_Amount
            Secondary_Magazine_Round_Amount
            Secondary_Knife
          }
          British_Role_Extras {
            __typename
            ... on ComponentLoadoutsThirdSlot {
              Third_Slot_Item
              Item_Amount
            }
            __typename
            ... on ComponentLoadoutsForthSlot {
              Forth_Slot_Item
              Item_Amount
            }
            __typename
            ... on ComponentLoadoutsFifthSlot {
              Fith_Slot_Item
              Item_Amount
            }
            __typename
            ... on ComponentLoadoutsSixthSlot {
              Sixth_Slot_Item
              Item_Amount
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

export default function Testing() {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(British);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return console.log("Api request error", error), (<p>Error :(</p>);

  return (
    <VStack>
      <Typography variant="h3">Testing with axios & GraphQL</Typography>
      {data.britishes.data.map((british) => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <TableTwo
            id={british.attributes.Role_Name}
            roll_name={british.attributes.Role_Name}
            primary={british.attributes.British_Roles[0].Primary}
            primaryMag={
              british.attributes.British_Roles[0].Primary_Magazine_Amount
            }
            secondary={british.attributes.British_Roles[0].Secondary}
            secondaryKnife={british.attributes.British_Roles[0].Secondary_Knife}
          />
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
      <TestingTable />
    </VStack>
  );
}
```

##### Table with props

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  Table,
  styled,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  tableCellClasses,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  Paper,
} from "@mui/material";

const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell)(({ theme }) => ({
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.head}`]: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
  },
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.body}`]: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
}));

const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)(({ theme }) => ({
  "&:nth-of-type(odd)": {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
  },
  // hide last border
  "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": {
    border: 0,
  },
}));

export const TableTwo = (props) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table sx={{ minWidth: 700 }} aria-label="customized table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <StyledTableCell>Roll</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">Primary</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">
                Primary Magazine Amount
              </StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">Secondary</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">Secondary Meele</StyledTableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            <StyledTableRow key={props.id}>
              <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                {props.roll_name}
              </StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">{props.primary}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">
                {props.primaryMag}
              </StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">{props.secondary}</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">
                {props.secondaryKnife}
              </StyledTableCell>
            </StyledTableRow>
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

##### Table with mapping inside

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  Table,
  styled,
  TableBody,
  TableCell,
  tableCellClasses,
  TableContainer,
  TableHead,
  TableRow,
  Paper,
} from "@mui/material";
import { useQuery, gql } from "@apollo/client";

const British = gql`
  query {
    britishes {
      data {
        attributes {
          Role_Name
          British_Roles {
            role_name
            Primary
            Primary_Sights
            Primary_Firing_Modes
            Primary_Magazine_Amount
            Primary_Magazine_Round_Amount
            Secondary
            Secondary_Firing_Modes
            Secondary_Sights
            Secondary_Magazine_Amount
            Secondary_Magazine_Round_Amount
            Secondary_Knife
          }
          British_Role_Extras {
            __typename
            ... on ComponentLoadoutsThirdSlot {
              Third_Slot_Item
              Item_Amount
            }
            __typename
            ... on ComponentLoadoutsForthSlot {
              Forth_Slot_Item
              Item_Amount
            }
            __typename
            ... on ComponentLoadoutsFifthSlot {
              Fith_Slot_Item
              Item_Amount
            }
            __typename
            ... on ComponentLoadoutsSixthSlot {
              Sixth_Slot_Item
              Item_Amount
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

const StyledTableCell = styled(TableCell)(({ theme }) => ({
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.head}`]: {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.common.black,
    color: theme.palette.common.white,
  },
  [`&.${tableCellClasses.body}`]: {
    fontSize: 14,
  },
}));

const StyledTableRow = styled(TableRow)(({ theme }) => ({
  "&:nth-of-type(odd)": {
    backgroundColor: theme.palette.action.hover,
  },
  // hide last border
  "&:last-child td, &:last-child th": {
    border: 0,
  },
}));

export const TestingTable = (props) => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(British);

  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return console.log("Api request error", error), (<p>Error :(</p>);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <TableContainer component={Paper}>
        <Table sx={{ minWidth: 700 }} aria-label="customized table">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow>
              <StyledTableCell>Roll</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">Primary</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">
                Primary Magazine Amount
              </StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">Secondary</StyledTableCell>
              <StyledTableCell align="right">Secondary Meele</StyledTableCell>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
          <TableBody>
            {data.britishes.data.map((british) => (
              <StyledTableRow key={british.attributes.Role_Name}>
                <StyledTableCell component="th" scope="row">
                  {british.attributes.Role_Name}
                </StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="right">
                  {british.attributes.British_Roles[0].Primary}
                </StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="right">
                  {british.attributes.British_Roles[0].Primary_Magazine_Amount}
                </StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="right">
                  {british.attributes.British_Roles[0].Secondary}
                </StyledTableCell>
                <StyledTableCell align="right">
                  {british.attributes.British_Roles[0].Secondary_Knife}
                </StyledTableCell>
              </StyledTableRow>
            ))}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </TableContainer>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
};
```

##### Postman returned data

```
{
    "data": {
        "britishes": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "attributes": {
                        "Role_Name": "British Squad Lead (Iron Sights)",
                        "British_Roles": [
                            {
                                "role_name": "British Squad Lead (Iron Sights)",
                                "Primary": "L85A2 + Foregrip + Bipod",
                                "Primary_Sights": "Iron Sights",
                                "Primary_Firing_Modes": "Auto/Single",
                                "Primary_Magazine_Amount": 7,
                                "Primary_Magazine_Round_Amount": 30,
                                "Secondary": "L131A1",
                                "Secondary_Firing_Modes": "Single",
                                "Secondary_Sights": "Iron Sights",
                                "Secondary_Magazine_Amount": 2,
                                "Secondary_Magazine_Round_Amount": null,
                                "Secondary_Knife": "SA80 Bayonet"
                            }
                        ],
                        "British_Role_Extras": [
                            {
                                "__typename": "ComponentLoadoutsThirdSlot",
                                "Third_Slot_Item": "L109A1 Fragmentation Grenade",
                                "Item_Amount": 2
                            },
                            {
                                "__typename": "ComponentLoadoutsForthSlot",
                                "Forth_Slot_Item": "L132A1 White Smoke Grenade",
                                "Item_Amount": 2
                            },
                            {
                                "__typename": "ComponentLoadoutsForthSlot",
                                "Forth_Slot_Item": "L152A1 Orange Smoke Grenade",
                                "Item_Amount": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "__typename": "ComponentLoadoutsForthSlot",
                                "Forth_Slot_Item": "L152A1 Yellow Smoke Grenade",
                                "Item_Amount": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "__typename": "ComponentLoadoutsFifthSlot",
                                "Fith_Slot_Item": "Field Dressing",
                                "Item_Amount": 2
                            },
                            {
                                "__typename": "ComponentLoadoutsSixthSlot",
                                "Sixth_Slot_Item": "Field Binoculars",
                                "Item_Amount": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "__typename": "ComponentLoadoutsSixthSlot",
                                "Sixth_Slot_Item": "Rally Point",
                                "Item_Amount": 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "attributes": {
                        "Role_Name": "British Squad Lead (SUSAT)",
                        "British_Roles": [
                            {
                                "role_name": "British Squad Lead (SUSAT)",
                                "Primary": "L85A2 + Foregrip + Bipod",
                                "Primary_Sights": "SUSAT Scope",
                                "Primary_Firing_Modes": "Auto/Single",
                                "Primary_Magazine_Amount": 7,
                                "Primary_Magazine_Round_Amount": 30,
                                "Secondary": "L131A1",
                                "Secondary_Firing_Modes": "Single",
                                "Secondary_Sights": "Iron Sights",
                                "Secondary_Magazine_Amount": 2,
                                "Secondary_Magazine_Round_Amount": null,
                                "Secondary_Knife": "SA80 Bayonet"
                            }
                        ],
                        "British_Role_Extras": [
                            {
                                "__typename": "ComponentLoadoutsThirdSlot",
                                "Third_Slot_Item": "L109A1 Fragmentation Grenade",
                                "Item_Amount": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "__typename": "ComponentLoadoutsForthSlot",
                                "Forth_Slot_Item": "L132A1 White Smoke Grenade",
                                "Item_Amount": 2
                            },
                            {
                                "__typename": "ComponentLoadoutsForthSlot",
                                "Forth_Slot_Item": "L152A1 Orange Smoke Grenade",
                                "Item_Amount": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "__typename": "ComponentLoadoutsForthSlot",
                                "Forth_Slot_Item": "L152A1 Yellow Smoke Grenade",
                                "Item_Amount": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "__typename": "ComponentLoadoutsFifthSlot",
                                "Fith_Slot_Item": "Field Dressing",
                                "Item_Amount": 2
                            },
                            {
                                "__typename": "ComponentLoadoutsSixthSlot",
                                "Sixth_Slot_Item": "Field Binoculars",
                                "Item_Amount": 1
                            },
                            {
                                "__typename": "ComponentLoadoutsSixthSlot",
                                "Sixth_Slot_Item": "Rally Point",
                                "Item_Amount": 1
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

##### Dev tools console log

[image: Dev tools console log]

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the .map call in your Testing component, it's creating a new table for each entry.

```
return (
    <VStack>
      <Typography variant="h3">Testing with axios & GraphQL</Typography>
          <TableTwo
            id={british.attributes.Role_Name}
            roll_name={british.attributes.Role_Name}
            primary={british.attributes.British_Roles[0].Primary}
            primaryMag={
              british.attributes.British_Roles[0].Primary_Magazine_Amount
            }
            secondary={british.attributes.British_Roles[0].Secondary}
            secondaryKnife={british.attributes.British_Roles[0].Secondary_Knife}
          />
      <TestingTable />
    </VStack>
  );
```

Comment: Hm okay I was unsure of this, because I had a feeling it would only render one result I used it like this `{data.britishes.data[0].attributes.Role_Name}` and it will only return the one result. But I cannot see why. I have a feeling its due to the way its returned from GrahpQl I have added the API result in the post. Anymore tips would be huge

Comment: If you only want to render one, you don't need a map at all. Map is specifically for rendering markup iteratively for each element in an array.  I can't really figure out how your data is structured, I think you need to make it conform to some kind of hierarchy, or just return an array of objects which contain all the data you need for a row. As it is it's extremely confusing.  And it seems like you're passing a lot of props to your table component that aren't used.

Comment: Okay I'll explore some other options thanks.